Change from baseline longitudinal model
I am working on a longitudinal model to analyze the change from baseline in a variable Y, measured at baseline Y1 and at subsequent time points (Y2, Y3, Y4 ...) for a set of patients. For each of these measurements, I also have the respective Standard Deviations (Y1_SD, Y2_SD, Y3_SD ...).
The (Change-from-baseline) Mean Difference (MD) is straightforward to compute as the difference between ( Y1 ) and each subsequent ( Y_i ). However, I am struggling to correctly define the Standard Deviation of the Mean Difference (SD_diff), given that this requires a correlation ( r ) between ( Y1 ) and ( Y2, Y3, ...); a correlation that is also required to code covariance matrix (eg Autoregressive Matrix)
The formula I am referencing for SD_diff is:
SD_diff = sqrt(S1² + S2² - 2 * r * S1 * S2)
My question is:

Do I need both elements to build a longitudinal model?
Can longitudinal models be coded only with covariance matrix?

How should variances and Covariance matrix be defined?
Given that any covariance matrix (eg AR(1)) includes the variable variance in its formulation; should this be defined by SD_diff? or by Yi_SD?



Change scores are typically not the best way to analyze longitudinal outcomes. See this page and others on this site. Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell’s Regression Modeling Strategies covers longitudinal models, including how to evaluate covariance structures that handle serial correlations.

Even if you ultimately want to present results as differences from baseline, you should not use the change from baseline as the outcome in a model that includes the baseline value as a predictor. This answer shows that changes are inherently correlated with baseline values. This page has extensive discussion of why such modeling is a bad idea.
You should instead model the later values (Y2, Y3, Y4, ...) with the baseline Y1 as a predictor, in a model that includes a function of time (and an interaction of that function with treatment, if any). As you want to use a covariance matrix to handle within-patient correlations, see Section 7.5 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies for choices of correlation structures in generalized least squares, and subsequent Sections for how to evaluate your choices. If you work with the actual Y_i values as the outcomes, you can just specify the overall correlation structure and let the model estimate the correlation magnitude for you from the data. The problems you envision with correlation structures based on change scores then disppear.
After you have built the model, you can use post-modeling tools like those in the R emmeans package to display the results in terms of differences from baseline (with confidence intervals), if you think that's useful to your audience. Just don't build the regression model with the change scores as the outcomes
